# No matter what year I put, my program is always telling me its a leap year, even when it is not

Tags: c

No matter what year I put its always telling it's a leap year

Comment: `argv[1]` should be `mm` as per `printf ( "Usage: ./dates mm dd yyyy \n" );` & check the entire thing.

Comment: what is `is_leap` doing inside `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring all of the other problems with your program for now, this condition...

```
else if ((yyyy % 4) || (yyyy % 100) && (yyyy % 400)) { 
  printf( "%d is a leap year", yyyy); }
```

... is true for any number that is either *not* divisible evenly by 4, or is *not* divisible evenly by both 100 and 400.  What you actually wanted was

```
else if ((!(yyyy % 4) && (yyyy % 100)) || !(yyyy % 400)) {
```

because the leap year rule in English is

- the year is a multiple of 4
- and is not a multiple of 100
- unless it is also a multiple of 400.

Comment: I'm not going to go step by step with you through the whole program.

Comment: now i am getting, this error:  dates.c: In function ‘is_leap’:
dates.c:42:59: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
   return ((!yyyy % 4) && (yyyy % 100) || !(x (yyyy % 400)); }
          ~                                                ^
                                                           )
dates.c:42:60: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
   return ((!yyyy % 4) && (yyyy % 100) || !(x (yyyy % 400)); }

Answer (score 1):

While it is tempting to use "clever" code like:

```
  int is_leap (int y) {
    return (!( yyyy % 4) || !( yyyy % 100) && (yyyy % 400));}
```

it is a temptation best avoided. This is nearly impossible to understand and will be a pain to debug, and will not produce better code.  Something like:

```
int is_leap(int y) {
    if (0 == (y % 400)) return 1;
    if (0 == (y % 100)) return 0;
    return 0 == (y % 4);
}
```

This code is easy to read and debug, and any decent compiler will produce code just as good as your complex expression if not better.